# Parsing JSON feed (WP feed) into React Native feed page

Tags: javascript, android, ios, json, react-native

I am not seeing any result in my simulator when I am parsing JSON feed (Wordpress JSON feed) into my React Native feed page, following is the code I am using;

----------AppBody.js----------

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
    import {Content, Container, Card, CardItem, Body} from 'native-base';

    import AppBodyData from './AppBodyData';

    export default class AppBody extends Component {

      constructor() {
        super()
        this.state={
          data:[]
        }
      }

      getData() {

        return fetch('https://www.rayaccountants.co.uk/feed/json')
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({data: responseJson.items});
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
              });
      }

      componenetDidMount(){
        this.getData();
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Container style={{
            marginTop: 100
            }}>
          <AppBodyData data={this.state.data}/>
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }

    module.export = AppBody;
```

----------AppBodyData.js----------

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
    import {Content, Container, Card, CardItem, Body} from 'native-base';

    export default class AppBodyData extends Component {
      render() {

        let articles = this.props.data.map(function(articlesData, index) {
          return (
            <Card>
              <CardItem>
                <Body>
                  <Text>
                    {articlesData.title}
                  </Text>
                </Body>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
          )
        });

        return (
          <Container style={{
            marginTop: 60
          }}>
            <Container>
              {articles}
            </Container>
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }

    module.export = AppBodyData;
```

Following is what I am getting on my simulator, wonders what I might have overlooked?

[iOS Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXgGI.png)

Comment: Add some log messages to identify where exactly is your problem. For example, does the json file get properly parsed? Is the data in the right format in your `map` function? Does the `Container` render properly if you hardcode the `articles`?

Answer (score 1):

Change this `this.setState({data: responseJson.items})` to `this.setState({data: responseJson.items} ,() => console.log(this.state.data))` and you should be able to see whether you're getting the data correctly. If it does log then its just a styling issue and you might need to just add height/widths to see them rendered on the screen. Also you don't need to do `module.export` when you're doing `export default` already.

Comment: Thanks - its seems like I am not getting parsed data from the feed in my console, please see the screenshot of the console https://ibb.co/n59eua

Comment: Are you using Icon anywhere? all that error is saying is that you passed a string as a property to 'active' instead of a boolean...

Comment: Yes those warning messages are for those icons on the tabbar at the footer, nothing related to the JSON parsing data issue...